# Heating effect on metals

Tags: electric-current

Why does a metal emit photon on heating? Where this photon came from as soon as the metal is heated? What makes the metal to emit photon while heating?

Comment: All materials that have a temperature above absolute zero (which means all materials) emit radiation whose wavelength depends on their temperature.  Heating doesn't change this, it just results in the emission of shorter wavelengths as the heated object's temperature increases.

Comment: @David White ... or rather, the emission spectrum depends on temperature.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does a metal emit photon on heating?

It is not only metal, all matter radiates according to the [black body radiation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html)  (approximately). The shape of the spectrum depends on the temperature. Heat applied to a metal raises the temperature and higher frequencies which fall within the visual range (red hot) start appearing.

> Where this photon came from as soon as the metal is heated?

Photons are quantum mechanical entities, and appear due to the underlying quantum mechanical nature of everything. For metals in particular, the microscopic view is that there are [lattices](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_Chem1_(Lower)/07%3A_Solids_and_Liquids/7.01%3A_Matter_Under_the_Microscope) of atoms, held together with spill over electromagnetic forces, although the atoms and molecules are neutral. The atoms and ,molecules in the lattice vibrate and rotate and these motions generate photons according to quantum electromagnetic rules. The higher the temperature the higher the frequency of vibrations and the frequency of the photons generated from them.

I have said "approximately" follows the theoretical black body curve, because there also exist atomic and molecular transitions that can appear in the spectrum in addition to the black body radiation. See for example the radiation f[rom the sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight#Composition_and_power) (the yellow entry).

What makes the metal to emit photon while heating?